# How to trigger an Android LongClick in Xamarin UI Test

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, nunit, ui-testing, long-click

I've got a RecyclerView with a ActionMode which can be activated by a long click on a RecyclerView item.

How to trigger a long click in Android with Xamarin UI tests?
AndroidApp contains a method TouchAndHold(Func query) but this one seems not to trigger a long click.

Anyone here have a solution?

My code:

```
   Func<AppQuery, AppQuery> test = c => c.Marked("Test");
   app.WaitForElement (test);
   app.TouchAndHold (test);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TouchAndHold should trigger a LongClick.

I forgot to build a new release apk where i implemented the OnLongClick functionality. After building a new apk the TouchAndHold worked as expected